# Accessing relationship in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following table schemas and assuming everyone only has 1 friend, how can I access the friends name in SQL? The following query returns id, name, and salary, but I want to return each friend as well. I'm very new to sql so these relationships are extremely confusing at the moment, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

`select s.id, s.name, i.salary from students as s join incomes as i on s.id = i.id;`

[image: table schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each friend also be a student, you need to join `students` -> `friends` -> `students`:

```
SELECT
    s1.id,
    s1.name,
    i1.salary,
    s2.id,
    s2.name,
    i2.salary
FROM students s1
INNER JOIN friends f
    ON s1.id = f.id
INNER JOIN students s2
    ON f.friend_id = s2.id
INNER JOIN incomes i1
    ON s1.id = i1.id
INNER JOIN incomes i2
    ON s2.id = i2.id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in there.  It should be `i1.salary` and `i2.salary`.